# Do I need to pay in full for hostel reservation to show proof of accommodation for a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, bookings, hostels, proof-of-accommodation

I am applying for a Schengen visa to travel to Germany and one of the requirements is showing proof of accommodation. I booked all my hostels via hostelworld.com, but only paid the non-refundable deposit (a couple of dollars for each place) instead of the entire amount. I intend to pay the rest of it on arrival at the hostel (or cancel it and go CouchSurfing, thus saving money).

But for the visa application, will the non-refundable deposit be enough to show proof of accommodation?

The reason I ask is, I emailed one of the hostels requesting a document showing my name and accommodation confirmation, and they replied saying they could only give me such a document once I pay in FULL.

Is this how I'm supposed to book for all places?

Have I been doing it wrong all this while (by only paying the tiny non-refundable deposit instead of full hostel fare)?

Answer (score 2):

No, only a reservation is required.  In fact, it is recommended you do not pay for your ticket (or hotel) until after your visa is secured.

I do not know how hostels operate as I have never stayed in one (except boarding school), but for **hotels** you generally reserve (with your credit card) and then pay when you check-in.

To do this you must book at the hotel's website and not some third party travel service (like expedia/travelocity/hotels.com) because these properties have pre-booked the rooms and need to sell them to you outright.

For a definitive source on this, you can visit the embassy/foreign mission website of any Schengen member state, or a generic site like [schengenvisainfo.com](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-application-requirements/).

Here is a snippet from the [Netherlands Embassy in Kuwait](http://kuwait.nlembassy.org/binaries/content/assets/postenweb/k/koeweit/netherlands-embassy-in-kuwait/import/visa_for_the_netherlands/all_other_visas/visa-requirements-schengen.pdf) (pdf link, relevant info pasted here, with my emphasis):

> APPLICATION REQUIREMENTS FOR TOURIST VISA
>
> 1. Duly filled application form with 1 recent photograph (NOT OLDER THEN 6 MONTHS) with white or grey background color passport size.
> 2. Passport valid at least 3 months after expiry date of the visa.
> 3. Copy of holder page travel document.
> 4. Copy of ID card if applicable.
> 5. Previous passport if any.
> 6. **Copy of flight reservation and hotel booking for the entire period of stay in Schengen Area.**
> 7. Copy of travel insurance, minimum coverage €30,000 (thirty thousand) valid for Schengen Area for the duration of your stay.
> 8. The visa fee equivalent of €60.00 (sixty) in KWD, cash only.
> 9. Letter from the employer/sponsor stating how long you have been working for the company, what is your designation (position) and how
>      much is your monthly salary (Kuwaiti nationals exempted).
> 10. Valid Kuwaiti residence permit endorsed in passport.
> 11. Proof of social/ economic ties; original bank statements of the last 6 months (Kuwaiti nationals exempted).

Note that this only applies for tourist visas, for business visas you don't need to show a hotel reservation.

Comment: One more rquirement in the hotel booking is your debit/credit card details should appear, else they willn't consider it. I clarified it from the Dutch embassy in UK when I applied for a Schengen visa.